# SQLite - How to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I wanted to get information about streaks of certain challenges from my database. I experimented with all of my queries in sqliteonline.com and therefore I found a query which meets my requirements to get these information:

```
select challengeid, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, count(*) as length from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by challengeid order by date) as seqnum from ACTIVE_CHALLENGES_TABLE t) t group by challengeid, date(date, '-' || seqnum || ' day') HAVING challengeid = 4 AND value != 0
```

Everything works fine on sqliteonline.com, but when it comes to Android Studio I get following error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select challengeid, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, count(*) as length from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by challengeid order by date) as seqnum from ACTIVE_CHALLENGES_TABLE t) t group by challengeid, date(date, '-' || seqnum || ' day') HAVING challengeid = 4 AND value != 0

I already tried finding out what causes the error. Throughout testing I found out that it could be the use of this snippet: `SELECT row_number() OVER (challengeid) seqnum from ACTIVE_CHALLENGES_TABLE`

I don't know what I should do. Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you using an older version of SQLite that doesn't support window functions?

Comment: The version is 3.9.2

Comment: That is quite old.  You should probably upgrade the database.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQLite does not support window functions you can use a correlated subquery to get the column `seqnum`:

```
select challengeid, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, count(*) as length 
from (
  select t.*,
    (
      select count(*) + 1 from ACTIVE_CHALLENGES_TABLE 
      where challengeid = t.challengeid 
      and (date < t.date or (date = t.date and rowid < t.rowid))
    ) as seqnum 
  from ACTIVE_CHALLENGES_TABLE t
  where t.challengeid = 4 and t.value != 0
) 
group by challengeid, date(date, '-' || seqnum || ' day')
```

Note that I removed the `HAVING` clause, which does not make sense since it does not filter out any aggregated columns and I replaced it with a `WHERE` clause inside the subquery, since you want results only under the condition:

```
challengeid = 4 and value != 0
```